# PS - Get All SMB shares with permissions

Tags: windows, powershell, server, acl

I'm trying to get all smb shares on my windows server with all user permissions on them for inventory check.

This is what i have:

```
$Shares = Get-SmbShare

foreach($Share in $Shares)
{
    Get-SmbShareAccess -Name $Share.Name | Where-Object {$_.AccountName -Match "DOMAINNAME"} 
}
```

Which gets me all domain users with their shares and which access they have.

But it only shows name of folder. I would like its gonna show full path on the server (Not UNC)

And it would be exportable in csv format.

When i do:

```
$Shares = Get-SmbShare

foreach($Share in $Shares)
{
    Get-SmbShareAccess -Name $Share.Name | Where-Object {$_.AccountName -Match "PRAGUELOFTS"} | Export-Csv -Path C:\perms.csv
}
```

It only exports the last user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your output columns very precisely when you pass to `Select-Object` an array of hashes in this format: `@{name="xyz"; expr={ calculated value }}`.

This way you can unify values from multiple sources, such as "share" and "share access", and manually calculated values, into one custom result.

```
Get-SmbShare | Where-Object Special -eq $false | ForEach-Object {
    $share = $_
    $share | Get-SmbShareAccess | Where-Object AccountName -Match "DOMAINNAME" | Select-Object @(
        @{name="UncPath";   expr={ "\\" + $env:COMPUTERNAME + "\" + $share.Name }}
        @{name="LocalPath"; expr={ $share.Path }}
        @{name="Account";   expr={ $_.AccountName }}
        @{name="Type";      expr={ $_.AccessControlType }}
        @{name="Right";     expr={ $_.AccessRight }}
    )
}
```

You can then go on and pipe this into `Export-Csv -Path C:\perms.csv`.

---

As for your second question - this

```
foreach ($Share in $Shares)
{
    Get-SmbShareAccess -Name $Share.Name | Export-Csv -Path C:\perms.csv
}
```

only gives you the last result in the CSV file because it literally says "for each share, write a CSV file". You keep overwriting the same file in every loop iteration.

Collect all the results into a variable first

```
$results = foreach ($Share in $Shares) {
    # ...
}
```

and *then* create the output file

```
$results | Export-Csv -Path C:\perms.csv
```

Comment: You're genius. Exactly what i needed. Didnt know i can do that. Marked as right answer.

Comment: @JohnyWave You can shorten it to `@{n="xyz"; e={ calculated value }}` if you want to save some typing, but personally I prefer scripts that are easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

My approach for a single server:

```
$daBears = "SERVERNAMEHERE"
$smbShares = Get-SMBShare -CimSession $daBears 
foreach($Share in $smbShares)
{
    Get-SmbShareAccess -Name $Share.Name -CimSession $daBears 
}
```